# How to set text to autocomplete textviews in android kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a spinner item with a list of items. I also have already selected item for that spinner item. How do I set that selected item as default value when the spinner appears?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using

```
spinner.setSelection(selectedIndex)
```

where selectedIndex is the index  of the item in the list which is to be selected.